# SOAP request from VBA

Tags: excel, vba, soap

I want to make SOAP request using VBA excel
VBA request

```
Public Sub httpclient()
        Dim Req As Object
        Dim sEnv As String
        Dim Resp As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
        Set Req = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        Set Resp = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")
        Req.Open "GET", "https://api.etadirect.com/soap/capacity/?wsdl", False
        sEnv = sEnv & "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope"">"
         sEnv = sEnv & "  <soapenv:Header/>"
         sEnv = sEnv & "  <soapenv:Body>"
         sEnv = sEnv & "   <Request>"
         sEnv = sEnv & "    <now>2019-07-22</now>"
         sEnv = sEnv & "    <login>string</login>"
         sEnv = sEnv & "    <company>string</company>"
         sEnv = sEnv & "    <auth_string>string</auth_string>"
         sEnv = sEnv & "   </Request>"
         sEnv = sEnv & "  </soapenv:Body>"
         sEnv = sEnv & "</soapenv:Envelope>"
    ' Send SOAP Request
        Req.Send (sEnv)
        Debug.Print Req.responseText
    End Sub
```

SOAP UI request

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:toa:capacity">
       <soapenv:Header/>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <urn:get_quota_data>
             <user>
                <now>2019-07-22</now>
                <login>string</login>
                <company>string</company>
                <auth_string>string</auth_string>
             </user>
          </urn:get_quota_data>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

I expected to obtain result below instead I obtain lot of xml tags.

```
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
       <SOAP-ENV:Body>
          <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
             <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode>
             <faultstring>Bad request format - Mandatory parameter is absent: 'date'</faultstring>
             <detail>
                <errorCode>100</errorCode>
             </detail>
          </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
       </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

SOAPUI return mandatory parameter is absent because i write the request only to authenticate.
In the same in vba i don't receive this message
The question is what I did wrong in VBA code.
Can you please help me?
Best regards,

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Please edit your question to include a problem description

Comment: `Bad request format - Mandatory parameter is absent: 'date'`... doesn't sound too mysterious to me. We should know the backend to reply with certitude, but as a simple guess I imagine that the parameter you're passing as `<now>`should rather be called `<date>`.

Comment: Check you are using latest endpoint and as per @MatteoNNZ comment the correct field appears to be date. At least according to [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/august2017/fieldservicecs_gs/FASDK/CapacityManagement_API-8.htm#FASDKth_Methods)

Answer (score 0):

My main trouble was proper declaration of the SOAP tags soapenv (generic) and sear (particular to the service).
This VBA function gets any number of nodes, although in my case I was only interested in one of several thousand objects available from the web service.

```vb
Public Function GetWebServiceData() As String
On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Dim xmlhttp As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim URL As String
    Dim qry As String
    Dim result As String
    
    Dim xmlDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Dim xmlNodeList As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
    Dim xmlNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode

    ' Construct the URL to call the web service with the parameters

     URL = "http://[redacted url to one endpoint]"
    
    qry = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" >" & _
    "<sear:searchEquipment xmlns:sear=""[http://[redacted]]/]"">" & _
               "<soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body>"
    qry = qry & "<sear:searchEquipment>"
    qry = qry & "<sear:queryDate>2023-03-09T00:00:00Z</sear:queryDate>"
    qry = qry & "<sear:searchType>Equipment</sear:searchType>"
    qry = qry & "<sear:searchBy>EQUIP</sear:searchBy>"
    qry = qry & "<sear:searchValue>25DG-105</sear:searchValue>"
    qry = qry & "</sear:searchEquipment>"
    qry = qry & "</soapenv:Body>" & _
               "</soapenv:Envelope>"
    
    ' Open the URL and get the response
    xmlhttp.Open "POST", URL, False 
    xmlhttp.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
    'Debug.Print qry
    xmlhttp.Send qry
    result = xmlhttp.ResponseText
    
    ' Load the XML document from a string
    Set xmlDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    xmlDoc.LoadXML result
    
    ' Extract the values from the XML document
    Set xmlNodeList = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("[redacted]")(0).ChildNodes
    
    For Each xmlNode In xmlNodeList
        Select Case xmlNode.nodeName
            Case "owner"
                
            Case "assignedLocation"
            Case "currLoc"
            'Case "id"
            Case "plate"
            Case "vin"
            Case Else
                ' ignore
        End Select
        Debug.Print xmlNode.nodeName, xmlNode.Text
    Next xmlNode
    
    
    GoTo CleanUp
ErrHandler:
    result = Err.Description
    Resume CleanUp
    Resume 'debugging only
CleanUp:
    ' Return the result
    GetWebServiceData = result
End Function
```