# SOAP(wsdl) request from VBA

Tags: vba, soap, service, wsdl

I've got SOAP service like below:

```xml
 <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Imports">
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://plum1:8524/iPlanistaService.svc?xsd=xsd0" namespace="http://tempuri.org/"/>
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://plum1:8524/iPlanistaService.svc?xsd=xsd1" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"/>
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://plum1:8524/iPlanistaService.svc?xsd=xsd2" namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/iPlanistaWebService"/>
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://plum1:8524/iPlanistaService.svc?xsd=xsd3" namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/UtilitiesDBPlum"/>
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://plum1:8524/iPlanistaService.svc?xsd=xsd4" namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/iPlanistaDBProject"/>
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://plum1:8524/iPlanistaService.svc?xsd=xsd5" namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic"/>
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://plum1:8524/iPlanistaService.svc?xsd=xsd6" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"/>
</xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="IiPlanistaService_GetWoNoByUID_InputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetWoNoByUID"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="IiPlanistaService_GetWoNoByUID_OutputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetWoNoByUIDResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:operation name="GetWoNoByUID">
<wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IiPlanistaService/GetWoNoByUID" message="tns:IiPlanistaService_GetWoNoByUID_InputMessage"/>
<wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IiPlanistaService/GetWoNoByUIDResponse" message="tns:IiPlanistaService_GetWoNoByUID_OutputMessage"/>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="GetWoNoByUID">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IiPlanistaService/GetWoNoByUID" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
```

I want to get manufacturer number from service. I have to call service GetWoNoByUID with one parameter (serial number).
I've found the code:

```
Set objXML = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP") 'Define http client
strURL = "http://plum1:8524/iPlanistaService.svc?wsdl"
objXML.Open "POST", strURL, False, "user", "password"
objXML.setRequestHeader "content-type", "text/xml"
objXML.send "GetWoNoByUID=1005460787"
```

After debugging I've got objXML.status=400 ("Bad request"). I think that something wrong is with setRequestHeader or Send. Any suggestions?

Comment: The payload is not a SOAP request. Create a working payload with something like SoapUI and put that in the send parameter

Comment: But how to do it?

Comment: First, you will have to find a different way of calling your SOAP service. VBA is not the place for that. Once you've found that, you will know what to put there. That way can be one of many. Try SoapUI. Give it the address of your wsdl and it'll create a template for you.

Comment: Previous example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75689249/478884   Plenty of other related posts: https://www.google.com/search?q=vba+soap+request+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: Can anyone give me example what set in setRequestHeader  and send ?