# Calling asmx web service by input parameters from VBA macro but SoapClient30 is missing

Tags: excel, vba, web-services, asmx, soap-client

I have an excel file with macro and that macro calls an asmx service. Macro and service was written 15 years ago. Excel macro calls that asmx service and service uploads data from excel cells to db.

15 years ago web service call was done like that :

```
Public soapService As SoapClient30
Set soapService = New SoapClient30
soapService.ClientProperty("ConnectorProgID") = "MSSOAP.WinInetConnector30"
soapService.MSSoapInit "http://blabla.com/ServiceName/Import.asmx?WSDL"
Call Module1.Add2DB_WebService
```

Add2DB_WebService is like that:

```
strResp = soapService.upload(inputParameter1, inputParameter2, inputParameter3, inputParameter4)
```

That macro works perfect but because we use Office Excel 2016, every time the pc which uses that excel file should include old dll because SoapClient30 is missing reference for years. So our IT dept put SoapClient30 dll to that pc and excel can run OK.

Now I have to make that excel macro run properly on Excel 2016.

I can’t reach and change the asmx service. I can’t write new API or etc. I have to call exactly the same asmx service.

As SoapClient30 is missing, it always says “Can't find project or library”

How could I make that macro run in Excel 2016? Any possible replacement for SoapClient30 ?

I would kindly ask your help.

I tried to call asmx service from VBA macro without SoapClient30 but couldn't succeed.

Comment: You'd need to look at the docs for the web service, and build the SOAP XML envelope in VBA.  It's more tricky than using the SOAP library, but definitely possible.  See for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57146366/soap-request-from-vba If you can track the HTTP calls from a workbook using the library (Maybe try Fiddler or something similar) then you can see what you need to replicate.

Comment: Thank you Tim. I created envelope string as I see at SoapUI sample, I succeed..

Comment: Good to hear you figured it out.