# VBA Schema in a SOAP request

Tags: vba, soap

I'm trying to get my head around SOAP API requests, I have queried plenty of API via REST using VBA with a JSON body just fine but the API I need to use now only takes SOAP requests. To that end how do you actually set up a SOAP request?

I have read around and they all use a seemingly different method, I tried the following on a test SOAP API to get a 200 response but then how would this be adapted to use a schema also?

```
Sub TestConnection()

    Dim http As New XMLHTTP60
    Dim xmldoc As Object, post As Object

    With http
        .Open "Get", "https://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/NumberConversion.wso", False
        .send
        Set xmldoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
        xmldoc.LoadXML .responseXML.XML
    End With
    
    
End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Using SOAP typically involves sending an XML document in the request body - it's not like making a regular REST Get request.  For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57146366/soap-request-from-vba If there's a specific SOAP endpoint you need to use then you will have to check out the docs for that endpoint.  It's not possible to give a tutorial on using SOAP here.

Comment: Do you actually need the XML document or can you add everything in the SOAP envelope body...? If I sent it line by line from my xsd schema for every tag?

Comment: The SOAP request typically sends an XML document (not the same as "XML file") in the body of the request.  I don't know what you mean by " If I sent it line by line from my xsd schema for every tag"  You'll need to do some reading up on SOAP and check out some examples.

Comment: @Drawleeh: start from here https://d-petre-bogdan.medium.com/the-wsdl-is-not-the-soap-web-service-97f307c4a90b Then use the examples from the service page https://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/NumberConversion.wso to see how the requests look like. Then just think of them as REST POST calls that need some headers and XML body.

Comment: That's a great article @Bogdan thank you.